# Why are my anonymous functions evaluating to NULL in Symfony 2.0?

Tags: php, symfony, anonymous-function, callable

I just started playing around with Symfony 2.0 and immediately ran into an error:

> [28-Nov-2011 16:51:26] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>   'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'A callable is expected in
>   AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader().'

Digging deeper, I found that an anonymous function was getting passed into the `registerLoader` function.

```
$callable = function($class) use ($loader)
{
  $loader->loadClass($class);
  return class_exists($class, false);
};

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader($callable);
```

Looks fine, right? Just to be safe, I threw in a check:

```
var_dump(gettype($callable));
```

Which returned NULL, which is obviously not callable. I just upgraded to PHP 5.3.2, and according to `phpversion()` that's the version that is getting used.

I ran a one-off script outside of the Symfony environment and everything behaved correctly.

```
$foo = function()
{
    echo 'foo';
};

var_dump(gettype($foo));
```

> //string(6) "object"

Anyone have any thoughts as to why I'm seeing different behavior around anonymous functions inside the Symfony environment?

Comment: Do you think this could have something to do with namespaces? I know them only since I started working with sf2, and I have encountered a lot of strange at the first look, explainable at the second look behaviours

Comment: Good question - I'll investigate namespaces further and see what I can find.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your config as stated in the [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html#checking-the-configuration) ?

This should tell you if you are missing anything required to run Symfony

Comment: Loading up the config page tells me 3 things, none of which seem related to this issue:

1. Install and enable a PHP accelerator like APC (highly recommended).
2. Install and enable the intl extension.
3. Set magic_quotes_gpc to off in php.ini*.